# How to increase swipe back area on iOS with react-native-navigation?

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

"react-native-navigation": "^7.17.1",

Swipe back area is very small and hard to trigger. How can I increase swipe back area?

And can I use pop gesture on Android?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the navigation options in StackNavigator. Maybe in your index.js

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="component_name"
      component={COMPONENT}
      options={{
        gestureResponseDistance: {horizontal: VALUE},   // change VALUE here
      }}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: No. react-native-navigation. Not react-navigation